# JavaFX - Clickable line on canvas

Tags: java, javafx

I have this JavaFX application that lets you plot locations on a map and connect them.

[image]

I do this by drawing a map as a background image on a canvas and then drawing circles and lines on it. I have made the circles clickable by using the contains() method in the Circle class, but how can I make the lines clickable?

edit: Look at this example where I just draw a line and set an event handler:

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    gc.setLineWidth(5);
    gc.strokeLine(100, 100, 200, 200);

    canvas.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        double x = event.getX(), y = event.getY();
    });
```

My question is simply this: how do I finish the event handler so that it detects if the click is inside the line I just drew?

Comment: Aren't you using a scene graph? And the `onMouseClicked` event handler?

Comment: I'm not using a scene graph, hadn't even heard of it before now. I am using onMouseClicked with canvas to detect if the x- and y coordinates of a click is inside a circle. But I have no idea how to check if it's inside a line.

Comment: I'd rather use the canvas for map display and on top of it you use nodes (Circle, Line, etc) and add an event handler to it. That's very easy to do. If you need an example, let me know.

Comment: Do you mean creating a Line object and adding an event handler to the Line object to detect if it's clicked? I tried to do that just now and I couldn't get the event handler code to run when the line was clicked.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And to the circles as well.

Comment: Do you really need to use a Canvas at all? Wouldn't it be better to use a `Pane` with an `ImageView` for the map, and then `Shape` subclasses?

Answer (score 14):

You should create a canvas and add the nodes (Circle, Line, etc) to it. Then you add mouse listeners to the nodes.

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragNodes extends Application {

    public static List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        drawShapes(gc);

        Circle circle1 = new Circle(50);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        circle1.setFill(Color.GREEN.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.7));
        circle1.relocate(100, 100);

        Circle circle2 = new Circle(50);
        circle2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        circle2.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.7));
        circle2.relocate(200, 200);

        Line line = new Line(circle1.getLayoutX(), circle1.getLayoutY(), circle2.getLayoutX(), circle2.getLayoutY());
        line.setStrokeWidth(20);

        Pane overlay = new Pane();
        overlay.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2, line);

        MouseGestures mg = new MouseGestures();
        mg.makeDraggable(circle1);
        mg.makeDraggable(circle2);
        mg.makeDraggable(line);

        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, overlay);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
        gc.strokeRoundRect(10, 10, 230, 230, 10, 10);
    }

    public static class MouseGestures {

        double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
        double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

        public void makeDraggable(Node node) {
            node.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

                orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();

                if (t.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                    Circle p = ((Circle) (t.getSource()));

                    orgTranslateX = p.getCenterX();
                    orgTranslateY = p.getCenterY();

                } else {

                    Node p = ((Node) (t.getSource()));

                    orgTranslateX = p.getTranslateX();
                    orgTranslateY = p.getTranslateY();

                }
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

                double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;

                double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

                if (t.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                    Circle p = ((Circle) (t.getSource()));

                    p.setCenterX(newTranslateX);
                    p.setCenterY(newTranslateY);

                } else {

                    Node p = ((Node) (t.getSource()));

                    p.setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                    p.setTranslateY(newTranslateY);

                }

            }
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: You are adding nodes to a pane not a canvas!